# How to know which function is used

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

[image]I have problem how to know which function is used, cause here is multiple implementation. How rails know which function is correct. How you solve this problem in Ruby, is there way to tell IDE which function will be used

Comment: The IDE tries to determine the correct method (or best match) by traversing the ancestors (superclasses, included modules) and via built-in rules. This works for many methods, but not for all. The safest way is to add a breakpoint (e.g. via `binding.pry`) to determine the method's origin at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ruby's Method#source_location
http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Method.html#method-i-source_location
You can use it with `binding.pry` as Stefan suggested or just print the result of #source_location before actually calling specific method (so you can be sure that the scope is the same).

Comment: So i see in examples in Rails controllers they use `:no_content` symbol to set head, but RubyMine can't fine where is `:no_content` set. So if i'm new in Ruby i can't read code, but i need to know where is that defined no to use symbols just to do stuff, but not to know form where they come. So how you know from where that `:no_content` come, not to debug just to read code?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with RubyMine's functionality, but without providing explicit source of the method - when method with the same name exists in another classes/modules - it would probably be impossible for that IDE to determine its origin.
IDE's help will only take you so far, that's when your own knowledge, docs and debugging comes in.
So `head` method - is defined in Rails' `actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/head.rb `
https://api.rubyonrails.org/
and :no_content is passed to `status` argument - to return status 204
https://www.rubydoc.info/github/rack/rack/Rack/Utils